# How is Clash of Clans added to the bottom of recent apps?

Tags: ios, multitasking, application-switcher, clash-of-clans

[image]

If I swipe it up, it opens Clash of Clans. 
May I know what feature is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing iOS's proactive suggestions - iOS learns your routine over time, and eventually suggests the apps it thinks you're about to open based on factors like location and time of day.